# How to successively transform a static page (image gallery) to a product type page?

Tags: search-engines

A website with about 700 static pages, where about 20 of these are basically the same page that displays products that are custom made in a image gallery like enviroment.

The point of having these pages is to attract people that search for different keywords in the same category. All products are built differently, with different materials, sizes, etc, even though they fall into one category.

I've noticed that this page does not receive a lot of visitors, and I would like to make it more "Product like" than an image gallery per se, attracting more visitors willing to buy such items.

I've done the following:

- Created a master page with all products, codes and material available

Then, in each page:

- A button to request a product quote with a form
- Material type (and option for different materials, so the same product can attract people looking for the same thing in a different material)
- Description of product
- Details
- Product code

But still, these will be static pages, and I can't really sell anything online, since all products are custom made to order.

What other techniques can I also apply so these pages become more "catalog like" to search engines? Is adding things such as "Buy such product" on keywords, and on description tags, title a good idea?
What else can I do to improve these pages visibility to potential customers?

**Note:** I'm not asking about user experience in these pages, I'm asking about search engines.

**Other considerations:** All pages are indexed by SEs, and most traffic comes from image search. All images are named after product (not product code), and they all have proper alt and title tags.

Thanks, 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be the use of the schema.org product markup in addtion to standard HTML, and good quality content above all. Good quality content includes the proper usage of header and paragraph tags, images, keyword highlights, keyword links, and also the new HTML5 content tags (it's always good to be prepared).

Comment: What do you mean by "keyword highlights"?

Comment: Depending on the context of the keyword make it a link to another relevant page, or make it bold.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought that was code for something. I followed your advice on markups, so I'm accepting the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Always glad to help :)